# Loss of quality passing images from viewcontroller iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiviewcontroller, photo-gallery

i'm developing an application that allows users to add masks at their photos, the app works well but i noticed a problem, i don't know why but the image loses quality.
i'm passing images to view controllers by using this method:

```
   AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

//SETTO STICKERS
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(_Image.frame.size.width, _Image.frame.size.height));
CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
[_Image.layer renderInContext:context];
UIImage *screenShot = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

appDelegate.ImageEnded = screenShot;
//Instanzio il viewController della main
LastViewController *VC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LastVC"];
//Vado alla main
[self presentModalViewController:VC animated:YES];
```

and by take the image from the other ViewController using the appdelegate, here is my full app-process:

> FirstScreen(ViewController) ->  TakePhoto or Select from gallery ->
>   AddMask(ViewController) -> AddStickers(ViewController) ->
>   LastViewcontroller(ViewController) .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` , the scale factor parameter defaults to 1.0.

As per the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContext) (emphasis mine):

> Discussion This function is equivalent to calling the
>   UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions function with the opaque
>   parameter set to NO **and a scale factor of 1.0**.

If you use it on a retina device, you'll see some quality loss.

You should use [UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIKitFunctionReference/#//apple_ref/c/func/UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions), and pass in 0.0 for the scale factor, which will default to the current main screen's scale factor. (1 for nonretina, 2 for retina devices).